# Tkinter window not opening in windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python 3.7. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
Root=Tk()
Root.mainloop()
```

Compilation is successful but gui window is not opening. I waited for a long time and had to close console manually. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please format the code properly. It is not clear what the problem might be if the code is malformed.

Comment: It either needs to have `Root = tkinter.Tk()` on the 2nd line, or `from tkinter import Tk` on the first.

Comment: Or `import tkinter as tk` then `root = tk.Tk()`

Answer (score 1):

On the first line, you need to put `from tkinter import *` instead of `import tkinter`.

This would be your final code:

```py
from tkinter import *
Root=Tk()
Root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I tried you code, but still no window is opening.

Comment: Are you getting an error @SounakBanerjee

Comment: No I am not getting any error, python is running, but no window is opening.

Comment: What editor are you using @SounakBanerjee

Comment: I am using spyder

Comment: Try selecting a console dedicated to Tkinter, or switch to a different editor. @SounakBanerjee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213433/discussion-between-themaker-and-sounak-banerjee).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tkinter 
Root=Tk() 
Root.mainloop()
```

As per the above, I think you have two options:

1. In first-line make a change : `from tkinter import *`
2. Or make a little bit change in your code as following:

```py
import tkinter as tk
Root = tk.Tk()
Root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please format your code properly? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the format . This is because i am new on stackoverflow

Comment: No problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!